# Account Sharing Violation

Tags: parse-platform

Is there any protection mechanism on Parse User system to avoid user from sharing accounts?
Use case: user paid for premium feature, than he shares the user/pass on the internet and thousands of users logs in and enjoy that paid feature.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about terms of use on another website.

Comment: Hi Brandon, my question is not about terms of use, it is about the actual functionality of Parse.com platform (which involves SDK for several different platforms). I think a lot of Parse.com users may have the same question and share the same workarounds if needed. Also, Parse.com uses stack overflow as its official Q&A system, the parse.com tag has more than 3K questions.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not, you would need to build such a system on your own using (not allowing concurrent use, tying to a single IP, maximum # requests in a given time period, etc).